# Time complexity of the Math.cbrt(a) method in java.math library

Tags: java, math

I have written java code for finding taxicab numbers using `math.cbrt(a)` function. I assumed the complexity of `math.cbrt(a)` is constant. I am really interested in knowing the complexity of this function such that I can know how good my algorithm works.
Visit [Finding taxicab Numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11410798/finding-taxicab-numbers/22241715?noredirect=1#comment41794817_22241715)

Comment: please refer this you could understand.

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2815/find-taxicab-numbers-in-on-time

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method is native, so exact call depends on VM implementation.
Eg. OpenJDK use fdlibm as you can check here
http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/share/native/java/lang/StrictMath.c

and fdlibm implementation is here
http://www.netlib.org/fdlibm/s_cbrt.c
which seems to be constant.