# Finding "taxiNumber" program, want to exchange nested for loop for optimization reasons

Tags: python, for-loop, nested

I just started programming 1 week ago so please forgive the chaos you are about to see
I'm trying to find the first x taxi numbers but with my "nested for loop" the program takes ages to go through all possibilities. 
Taxi number:
if there is a number a^3+b^3 that is equal to c^3+d^3
that sum is a taxinumber. Example 
12^3+1^3 == 10^3+9^3 == 1729

For me it's a success if i can find around 20 taxinumber
Thanks beforehand for any tips or tricks!

Here is my code:

```
import math    

def main():    
    numbersOfResultsToFind = getNumberOfTaxisToFind()
    foundResults = 0
    numberToCheck = 1    
    while(foundResults < numbersOfResultsToFind):
        result = getTaxi(numberToCheck)
        if len(result) > 1: #if more then one a+b
            foundResults = foundResults + 1
            print(numberToCheck, result)
        numberToCheck = numberToCheck + 1

def getNumberOfTaxisToFind():
    return int(input("How many taxinumbers do you want to find? "))                           

def getThirdSquareFloored(value):
    value = value**(1/3)
    value = math.floor(value) #floor value
    return value    

def getTaxi(numberToCheck):
    result = []
    upperLimit = getThirdSquareFloored(numberToCheck)
    for a in range(1, upperLimit+1):
        for b in range(1, upperLimit+1):                                                          
            aCubed = a**3
            bCubed = b**3
            sumCub = aCubed + bCubed            
            if(sumCub == numberToCheck and a < b):
                result.append((a, b))
    return result   

main()
```

Comment: There are a few things you could change to speed things up. For exanple, the order of `a` and `b` does not matter, so you can reduce the checks if you remove the duplicates like 1, 2 and 2, 1

Comment: Alright! Sounds good
That would only speed up the program a bit though? I mean to find the first 15 or 20 taxis, is this something worth doing?

Comment: The longer your loop is, the more the saving ;)

Comment: if you need `a < b` then you should use `for b in range(a+1, ....)`

Comment: You should do `aCubed = a**3` before `for b in ...` - now you calculate many times the same value.

Comment: Ye alright! Thanks
I will try!:)

Comment: You can calculate `diffCubes = numberToCheck - aCubed` before `for b` and later compare `diffCub == bCubed` - this way you don't have to use `+` so many times.

Comment: Inside `for b` you can even do `if bCubed >= diffCub: break` to make less calculations.

Comment: The first taxinumber is 1729
a^3+b^3=c^3+d^3 or 12^3+1^3=10^3+9^3
but i was thinking if i set say a to:
Instead of a^3+b^3=1729
a=(1729-b^3)^(1/3)
I think I could in someway change my program to not use the "for b in range" with some slight adjustments. I'm just not sure how yet^^

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the [**Taxicab numbers**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_number) are VERY far apart. You can do some math tricks to solve it. For example, you can be checking the [Euler's sum of powers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_sum_of_powers_conjecture). The problem with that approach is that you will be generating some taxi numbers, but they might not be in order.

As it goes to your code, I have some notes:

1. If you want to take the cubic root, do not do `value**(1/3)`! Remember that `1/3 = 0` in python. Use `1./3` or use `numpy`
2. Don't use the `**(1./3)` at all - any power functions are expensive, try replacing them with something (precomputed values?)
3. **Important:** [Read StackOverflow if there is a solution already!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11410798/finding-taxicab-numbers)

Comment: Thanks! Much appreciated
I will try to not use power functions in the future! Not sure how to change it for this specific problem though!

Answer (score 0):

```
import math           

def main():  
    numbersOfResultsToFind = getNumberOfTaxisToFind()
    foundResults = 0
    numberToCheck = 1 
    while(foundResults < numbersOfResultsToFind):
        result = getTaxi(numberToCheck)
        if len(result) > 1:
            foundResults = foundResults + 1
            print(numberToCheck, result)
        numberToCheck = numberToCheck + 1


def getNumberOfTaxisToFind():
    return int(input("How many taxinumbers do you want to find? "))


def getThirdSquareFloored(value):
    value = value**(1./3)
    value = math.floor(value)
    return value   

def getTaxi(numberToCheck):
    result = []
    upperLimit = getThirdSquareFloored(numberToCheck)
    for a in range(1, upperLimit+1):
        b = round((numberToCheck-a**3)**(1./3))
        if(a**3+b**3 == numberToCheck and a < b):
            result.append((a, b))
            if len(result) == 2:
                break
    return result
main()
```

Thanks so much for all help! This is my updated code, runs ALOT quicker. I set the b value to be calculated from a instead of using a nested for loop. I also implemented a if len(result), break in the end of my code
No reason to keep looking for pairs if one is already found